# Python : Extracting variables from a join

Tags: python, variables, join

I have joined two datasets in Spark (pySpark)and the output looks likes this

```
    (u'SomeThing', (u'ABC', u'500'))
```

I would like to do the following: Define a function that extracts and returns only ABC, 500. I wrote a function like this

```
       def extract_lasttwo_cols(three_cols):
       a,b,c = three_cols.split(',')
       return b,c
```

But this function results in an error "tuple object has no attribute split()"
Is it possible to extract the variables without saving the results as text files and then processing them?

Comment: You are working with a *tuple*, not a *string*. What is your question? How to access an element in a tuple? Have you tried the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples are immutable. `split()` is for `str` types.

This will return the b and c separately:

```
def extract_lasttwo_cols(three_cols):
    b, c = three_cols[1][0], three_cols[1][1]
    return b, c
```

Answer (score 1):

Your value is a tuple with two elements, whereby the second element is a tuple by itself

```
def extract_lasttwo_cols(three_cols):
    return three_cols[1]
```